# Преобразовать части строки, пропустив заданную подстроку

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

> текст_слева{текст_внутри_фигурных_скобок}текст_справа

Нужно с помощью регулярки преобразовать части строки, не внутри фигурных скобок, кастомной функцией, для примера можно использовать `mb_strtoupper`.

> ТЕКСТ_СЛЕВА{текст_внутри_фигурных_скобок}ТЕКСТ_СПРАВА

Comment: Способов как всегда, уйма, например вы можете разбить строку как вам нужно и выполнить манипуляцию, после этого склеить строку обратно. implode(), explode().

Comment: Это не особо изящно. Хотелось бы увидеть решение с помощью preg_replace_callback()

Comment: Что-то похожее на `([^{]+)(?>{)(?>[^}]+)(?>})(.*)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = "текст_слева{текст_внутри_фигурных_скобок}текст_справа" ;

$newStr = preg_replace_callback(
    '/^[^{]+\{|\}[^}]+$/',
    function($matches) {
        return mb_strtoupper($matches[0]) ;
    },
    $str
) ;

// $newStr == "ТЕКСТ_СЛЕВА{текст_внутри_фигурных_скобок}ТЕКСТ_СПРАВА"
```

Comment: Благодарю! А если исключить текст_внутри_фигурных_скобок и сами фигурные скобки?

Comment: @Dimas '/^[^{]+|[^}]+$/'

Comment: Спасибо! решено!